# OOP - Is it good practice to always use class methods instead of functions?

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Apologies for the long question.  I know how to use classes, but sometimes I struggle with *when* to use them.
My question is three-fold really..

**1)  Is it good practice to always use a class method, even when the class doesn't necessarily get/set any properties?**

For example, if I want a function to just spit out a HTML header, should I make this...

```
namespace Project1\UI;

class HTML
{
    public function makeHeader()
    {
        echo "<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body>";
    }
}
```

**2)  Do you build your own classes for things like database access, instead of calling the PDO extension directly?**
The code below is adding complexity, and is really just passing values on to the PDO:

```
namespace Project1\DB;
use \PDO;

class Database {

    private $pdo;
    private $statement;

    public function __construct() {

        require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'Project1/Config/Login.php';

        $pdo = new PDO(
            sprintf (
                'mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;port=%s;charset=%s',
                $settings['host'],
                $settings['name'],
                $settings['port'],
                $settings['charset']
            ),
            $settings['username'],
            $settings['password']
        );   

        $this->pdo = $pdo;
        return $pdo;
    }

    public function prepare($statement) {    
        $this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($statement);  
    }

    public function bind($placeholder,$value) {
        $this->statement->bindValue($placeholder,$value);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->statement->execute();      
        return $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }
}
```

**3)  If I want to use a global function, is there good practice for where to store these on disk?  Presumably I should put them in a separate file / namespace?**

```
/Project1/Logic/Validation.php << Contains a class
/Project1/Logic/Search.php     << Contains a class
/Project1/Logic/Compare.php    << OK to just contain a function?
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This is merely a request for opinions. There are not universally accepted rules about object oriented programming use or techniques.

Comment: Instead of trying to think of "what's better", consider the code you currently write and ask yourself "what's wrong?"  Is there a problem which can be solved?  There is no single correct design for all possible situations.  The "best" code is code which works while being simple to understand and support/maintain.  However you arrive at that goal is up to you.  As you maintain the code, look for "pain points" which can be addressed and address them.

Comment: Speaking of PDO wrappers, we are writing them, but to [improve our experience](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper), not to spoil it, like it happen [with your current wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to 1st and 3rd questions**

Yes, you may have classes that only implements functions without storing values in attributes. We call those *Helpers* by the way...

And no, its not a good idea to create a class for every single function you might have in your project. Keep in mind that the more files you need to include, the more reading/interpreting time your server will expend and it means a longer time to execute your script.

**Answer to 2nd question**

That is your call. I'd recommend extending native PDO class instead of using a [*Proxy Class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

PDO is a good class, you don't want to limit yourself or reinvent the wheel